# How to use multiple node_modules directories with TypeScript compiler?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm in the need to resolve multiple `node_modules` outside of my project directory. Currently I found no way for that using `paths`. As a very worst solution, I'll symlink these directories, but I dont't want to.

Comment: More information is required. Why do you need to do this? What is in your tsconfig?